# Disabling System Restore on a USB External Disk on *all* Windows machines?

Tags: windows, usb, system-restore

So I can disable System Restore on my USB External Disk by going to

> **System Properties** -> **System Restore** -> (selecting the drive) -> **Settings** -> **Turn off System Restore on this drive**

and this works wonderfully my own system.

But can I set an option (via an autorun.inf or some other mechanism) that will prevent System Restore from storing data on this drive when plugged into other Windows machines?

Comment: Does formatting it as FAT32 prevent **System Restore** data from being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/browse_thread/thread/2055c3b56db7280e/0fbdee306286b344?#0fbdee306286b344) from the Microsoft Product Manager for System Restore, this is not possible.  It looks like you will need to manually do this on each system.

Answer (score 1):

Does formatting it as FAT32 not prevent system restore data from being added?

TODO: Convert to comment once i have 50 cred

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not possible by simply adding some sort of file to the drive.  Although, I have never personally had a problem with other PC's trying to use an external drive for system restore automatically after I plug it in.

I have heard that if you unplug the drive while windows is running, without doing a "Safe Removal of Hardware", windows will not use that drive for System Restore though.